# Python Selenium timeout move to next item in loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a loop that takes a list of items and runs various functions on them...

```
def init_driver():
    ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("my_profile");
    ffprofile.add_extension(extension="myaddon.xpi")
    return driver

def check_item
    print ( "Checking Item : ")
    inputElement.submit()
    print ( "Submit has been pressed" )
    input(" Do Something Else ")
    timeelapsed = a + 1

driver = init_driver()

for i, item, in enumerate(item_list):
    check_item(item)
```

I am trying to add a try exception to inputElement.submit() so if for any reason it times out while running this (which it has been known to do) then it would break out of the loop and move to the next iteration.

I have tried using break but that doesn't work because I am not in the loop, can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

This is the timeout message I get

```
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for page load.
```

Comment: Could you also post how does it timeout - what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

for i, item, in enumerate(item_list):
    try:
        check_item(item)
    except TimeoutException:
        pass  # do nothing, TODO: log?
```

Comment: That looks good, but I am getting error : TimeoutException is not defined.  I have added the original timeout msg to the op

Comment: @fightstarr20 sure, added the import statement